# SBT 1.0.3 and -Djava.library.path

Tags: sbt

Today I tried to update our project from sbt 0.13.15 to 1.0.3.

Unfortunately the JVM property 
`-Djava.library.path=/custom/lib/` 
seems not to work the same way as before.

Current solution (works with 0.13.15):

```
 `sbt -Djava.library.path=/custom/lib/ run`
```

Until now, I tried the following things

1. Adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to env
2. Setting javaOptions in build.sbt like this

   ```
     `fork in run := true`

     `javaOptions in run += "-Djava.library.path=/custom/lib/"`
   ```

Unfortunately none of the solutions I found online seems to work and I will run into a Guice CreationException

> `Error injecting method, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no customlib in java.library.path`

Comment: Have you tried `JAVA_OPTS` env var or `.jvmopts` conf file?

Comment: Thank you, @laughedelic ! Using `JAVA_OPTS` works great! Don't know why I missed this before.

Comment: Then I'm going to write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternatively use`JAVA_OPTS` environment variable or `.jvmopts` configuration file. You can find it mentioned in the output of `sbt -help`:

```
  # jvm options and output control
  JAVA_OPTS          environment variable, if unset uses ""
  .jvmopts           if this file exists in the current directory, its contents
                     are appended to JAVA_OPTS
```